# Entity framework with mysql database migrations fail, when creating indexes

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

what causes this error in MySQL with entity framework? I can generate the migration script and connect to the database but it doesn't like the SQL generated particularly "hash" when trying to create indexes.

Example:

```
CREATE index  `IX_Facility_ID` on `Contact.Address` (`Facility_ID` DESC) using HASH
```

Error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order

Is there any way around this? This is with EF 6 and the latest mysql dlls.

Answer (score 7):

i haved the same problem, after i read on posts, i decided create a class inherits ofMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator and override ***protected override MigrationStatement Generate ( CreateIndexOperation op )***, then on configuration of migration i add : ***SetSqlGenerator ( "MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new myMigrationSQLGenerator ( ) );***

this is the code of class:

```
public class myMigrationSQLGenerator : MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    private string TrimSchemaPrefix ( string table )
    {
        if ( table.StartsWith ( "dbo." ) )
            return table.Replace ( "dbo.", "" );
        return table;
    }

    protected override MigrationStatement Generate ( CreateIndexOperation op )
    {
        var u = new MigrationStatement ( );
        string unique = ( op.IsUnique ? "UNIQUE" : "" ), columns = "";
        foreach ( var col in op.Columns )
        {
            columns += ( $"`{col}` DESC{( op.Columns.IndexOf ( col ) < op.Columns.Count - 1 ? ", " : "" )}" );
        }
        u.Sql = $"CREATE {unique} INDEX `{op.Name}` ON `{TrimSchemaPrefix ( op.Table )}` ({columns}) USING BTREE";
        return u;
    }
}
```

and this is the code on ***Migrations\Configuration.cs***:

```
    public Configuration ()
    {           
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator ( "MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new myMigrationSQLGenerator ( ) );
    }
```

this work for me.

Comment: This also helped me but I had a completely different problem related to my current culture (Swedish) which in turn couldn't parse the version of MySql. I got "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." when MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator was doing a ParseDouble. I have reported that as a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92561

Comment: Thank you guys! Iv'e spent the whole day trying to figure out why I couldn't create foreign key references between two tables. I hade the exact same problem as Björn (Swedish computer). I've learned one thing with this: Read the f***ing exception dump that tells you where to look!!

Comment: Old topic but this problem is still here with MySql Data EF 8.0.19.0, so thanks you for this workaround!!

Answer (score 2):

Looking the MySql source code, you need to add this(**anonymousArguments: new { Type = "BTrees" }**) on index definitions:

```
.Index(t => t.GroupId, anonymousArguments: new { Type = "BTrees" });
```

This is not a fix, but for the moment you can apply the migration code.

Comment: ugh, how infuriating, I've just wasted about half a day trying to track this down. It must be a really recent issue because I created a project about a month ago using the exact same steps and I didn't encounter this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think thread locale change prior DEFAULT generate methods is better solution than [henoc salinas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047931/entity-framework-with-mysql-database-migrations-fail-when-creating-indexes/51756143#51756143). There can be another hidden defects inside standard implementation as well as you will need to support this every time you update MySql packages.

Just change culture information prior calls and restore if you need afterwards.

Here is reworked version:

```
public class CustomizedMySqlMigrationSqlGenerator : MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    #region Override members

    protected override MigrationStatement Generate(CreateIndexOperation op)
    {
        var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        try
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
            return base.Generate(op);
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
        }
    }

    ...
    //Same for all overriden Generate() methods

    #endregion
}
```

Also you can just specify thread locale before SetSqlGenerator method call if you don't care locale persistence (code first model)

Comment: Trying henoc salinas solution but your seem to be more secure with future MySql.Data.EF updates. This work perfectly. Tks