# MySQL Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF code-first migration to create database schema on MySQL. But it is giving error when I am going to execute command for update database as below.

> Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order

I followed all the steps given on [MySQL support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

I have tried to search on google and also in stackoverflow. But I couldn't get permanent solution to fix this issue.

```
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;port=3306;database=testdb;Uid=root;password=*******;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I using using MySQL Workbench 6.3.10. MySQL Server version is 8.0.11.

For the entity framework code-first, I am using below packages..

- EntityFramework - 6.2.0
- MySql.Data - 6.10.7
- MySql.Data.Entity - 6.9.12

When I used latest version of MySql.Data (8.0.11), it is giving me diffrent error :

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

Comment: I found solution for this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102420/ef-incorrect-usage-of-spatial-fulltext-hash-index-and-explicit-index-order.

Comment: I checked that solution earlier. But its not permanent solution. I need to replace manually everywhere.

Comment: see this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756143/7782179

on this i create a inherit class, override a function and set my custom class on configuration.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run `Update-Database -verbose` to see more logs and identify that EF try to execute a script with `` CREATE INDEX `IX_id` on `Table` (`col_Id` DESC) using HASH ``

This error is caused by `using HASH`.
The MySQL Server return the following message, if you try to create index using HASH.

> ### Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order

locate `.Index(t => t.col_Id)` or `CreateIndex("dbo.table", "col_Id")` in your migration scripts and change it as follow:

Try to use `BTrees` like this:

```
.Index(t => t.User_Id, anonymousArguments: new { Type = "BTrees"})
```

or

```
CreateIndex("dbo.table", "col_Id" , anonymousArguments: new { Type = "BTrees"}))
```

This worked for me.