# MySQL Entity Framework: Can't create index

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

I'm using MySql.Data.Entity version 6.10.8 with Entity Framework.
I'm doing "Code first" to let the MySql-provider create the database structure.
Whenever the migrations contains a creation of a Index my migration fails when running the update-database command. The error message and stack trace are as follows:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
>   at
>   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation
>   op)    at
>   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.<.ctor>b__22_4(MigrationOperation> op)    at
>   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable 1
>   migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GenerateStatements(IList 1
>   operations, String migrationId)    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.GenerateStatements(IList`1 operations, String migrationId)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable 1 operations,
>   IEnumerable 1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable 1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable 1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   Input string was not in a correct format.

How to repeat:
Use Swedish Windows (or any other language which do not use "." as the decimal separator).

Create a migration file with an index, such as:

```
CreateTable(
"dbo.AspNetRoles",
c => new
{
  Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128, storeType: "nvarchar"),
  Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256, storeType: "nvarchar"),
})
.PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
.Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex"); // This line causes the exception
```

Run database-update

(A bug report has been sent to MySql: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92561)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is due to MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation op) which checks the version of the database by converting a string to double. However it does so without specifying an IFormatProvider. Since Swedish use "," as the decimal separator this conversion fails (the version number is separated by ".").

By overriding MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation op) this can be avoided. Use the code from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756143/1037864 (which is an answer for a different question)

Comment: Your right, but the better answer should be BlackGad's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707831/5250701 in the answer you quote.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasC, that seems like a good solution. Since I have not tried it myself i wont change my answer right now. Also, according to an answer for my bug ticket this should now out-of-the-box work in version 8.0.19.